# MDX: Do you have to use ORDER when using RANK?

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

Will RANK get confused if you have not ORDERed the data?

Will the resulting ranking column contain garbage or would it just return #ERROR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was only the case for 2000 (so says Wiley's "MDX Solutions")

Answer (score 2):

No, it will return a valid value (the ordinal position of the specified tuple in the set)

Rank (MDX)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144726.aspx